# Copy nine-patch borders by command line

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have a series of images which I want to use as nine-patches to represent the different states of a button. Is there a command line tool to copy the border pixels from one `.png` to the next? It could save me an hour of clicking.

Comment: Just making sure you are aware of: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Comment: That works. Copy to answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Asset Studio by Roman Nurik is set of tools to relieve some of the tasks required by Android developers and designers. For a while parts of it was in the Eclipse ADT plug-in: http://tools.android.com/recent/assetstudiointegration

Start here:
https://github.com/romannurik/AndroidAssetStudio

For Nine Patch related content you should look at Simple Nine Patch Generator:

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

and see if it is of assistance.